# \ul collapses the frame title to a black bar

Tags: beamer, underline, frame-title

I'm trying to underline all frame titles in Beamer in the same manner as my title page:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTFoj.png]

However, instead of the intended result, I get a black bar/square where the frame title was supposed to be.

A compilable version would be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\makeatletter
\let\UL\ul
\renewcommand\ul{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \UL}
\makeatother
\setulcolor{orange}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\ul{\MakeUppercase{\inserttitle}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{test}
{
  \vspace{16pt}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\ul{\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{Testtest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle  
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
  Introduction
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Do you realy want that underlining?

Comment: Thank you! The underlining is important to me. I posted something which should be compilable below. You need both comments for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the MWE throws an error:

```
! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

See the soul package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.42 \end{frame}
```

Probably you are compiling in `nonstopmode` where LaTeX tries to continue after an error - this is however usually not a good idea because the output can be wrong as you have experienced. The `soul` manual mentions for this error (p. 5):

> You get a Reconstruction failed error and a black square like ⬛ in the DVI file where you violated this rule.

The rule mentioned is "Grouping hyphenatable material". The definition of `\insertframetitle` (from `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) is indeed very complex:

```
\gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}%
```

where `#2` is the argument provided to `\begin{frame}`.

So, the issue is that `soul` is unable to process `\insertframetitle` in such a way that it knows what to underline.

Luckily, `beamer` also defines a much simpler internal macro when processing `\begin{frame}`:

```
\gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
```

This macro can be used by `soul` without problems. Because the macro is internal and has an `@` symbol you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the definition of the beamer template.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\makeatletter
\let\UL\ul
\renewcommand\ul{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \UL}
\makeatother
\setulcolor{orange}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\ul{\MakeUppercase{\inserttitle}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{test}
{
  \vspace{16pt}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\ul{\MakeUppercase{\beamer@frametitle}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\title{Testtest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle  
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{My Frame Title}
  Introduction
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]